# OpenGL GLint, GLsizei limit?

Tags: c, opengl, types, limit

OpenGL define its own datatype. Such as `GLint` or `GLsizei`. And they are different across platforms. Where can I find limits for the types?

### Edit

Added language tag to clarify domain. And I know that GL* types will be resolved into basic C types, but it can be different by platform. (actually that's why they are defined.) And even basic C types are not guaranteed to be fixed size on any platform. That's why the `limit.h` is exist, and I expect there's also similar thing in GL itself for GL* types because they're semantically different with C types, and it means they need their own limit definitions.

Comment: @Chimera Hmm I think *OpenGL* means C API unless any language binding specified explicitly :)

Comment: I don't think questions should be written that expect such assumptions. *Especially* when the answer to the question could very well depend on the language being used.

Comment: @Chimera Well... actually, that's not assumption. Strictly saying, *OpenGL* or *OpenGL ES* means only C API *officially*, and other language bindings are just wrapper libraries. So when we saying *OpenGL*, it's C-API by default. http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Writing_an_OpenGL_Application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using C++ you can use `std::numeric_limits<GLint>::max()` to get the correct maximum value for a type or any other property of the type.

The spec doesn't guarantee that `GLint` is actually an `int` on any platform but only that it is an at least 32bit wide signed integral type, so MAX_INT is the lower size bound on a platform where `int` is actually 32 bits wide (e.g. `x86_64`).

Comment: I think I can use C++ if required. Can I assume this is guaranteed to be safe by GL specification?

Comment: I set yours as answer because I could find minimum bit spec in specification as you mentioned in comment on other answer :)

Comment: For later ref, for OpenGL ES 2.0, spec is here: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf p.12, 2.4 Basic Operations, Table 2.2 GL Data Types. Looks like there's no pre-defined C level symbols for limits.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: Note that as pmr points out from the OpenGL spec, it is not guaranteed that `GLint` or `GLsizei` will always be defined as `int`. `GLint` and `GLsizei` are only guaranteed to be at *least* 32 bits.**

from GL/gl.h

```
typedef int GLint;
typedef int GLsizei;
```

Those type are int's and sized according to the platform. To get the min and max values you can use INT_MIN and INT_MAX which should be found in limits.h ( assuming C ).

Comment: And they are typedef's to int. So you can get the size using INT_MIN and INT_MAX as they will ALWAYS be INTS.

Comment: Actually `GLint` will be an `int` regardless of the platform. The size may change as reflected in INT_MIN and INT_MAX.

Comment: From OpenGL 4.3 Core page 13: "...GLint outside this document, and is not necessarily equivalent to the C type `int`" The size of GLint is 32bits, `int` might not be 32 bits on every platform.

Comment: Well, see you can learn something new everyday. Thank you for the clarification. I guess what I read wasn't clear or accurate.